# Can you trash fortress indefinitely with donate?

Tags: dominion, dominion-dark-ages, dominion-empires

So the two cards* in question here are Fortress, which reads:

> +1 Card
>
> +1 Action
>
> ---
>
> When you trash this put it into your hand

and Donate which reads:

> After this turn, put all cards from your deck and discard pile into your hand, trash any number, shuffle your hand into your deck, then draw 5 cards.

And the question is whether after a Fortress returns to your hand can you trash it again with the same Donate, and thus trash the same Fortress a potentially unbounded number of times.

This question actually matters since the landmark Tomb grants a player +1 point for every card they trash, thus this scheme could potentially net an unlimited number of points if Tomb is active.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, because you trash all cards simultaneously.

From the [Dark Ages rulebook](https://www.riograndegames.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Dominion-Dark-Ages-Rules.pdf):

> When two or more cards are trashed at the same time, such as due to Count, first trash them all, then pick an order to resolve things that happen due to trashing them.

So with Donate, you must trash all of the cards you want to trash at the same time; and only then do any trashed Fortresses trigger and return to your hand.

There is also a [ruling](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Chapel) for Chapel, which uses basically the same wording:

> You choose all the cards you want to trash, and then trash them at the same time; you don't trash them one-by-one. This matters for interactions with Dark Ages cards with on-trash abilities.